# Cluster regression

Tags: regression, clustering, sample, cluster-sample, research-design

I have a dataset and divided the sample into 6 groups based on 4 binary criteria (e.g. "1" for has a Chief Digital Officer and "0" otherwise).

Now I want to conduct a regression of the clusters on the profit of the company.

Would a command like the following be appropriate in your opinion? Is this a command practice in research? Any reference from literature would be more than welcome!

```
reg profit i.groups
```

Otherwise: How would you proceed?

Many many thanks!

Comment: It would help to resolve the many ambiguities in this question before trying to answer it.  Are "cluster" and "group" synonyms?  Did you truly "divide" the data into *nonoverlapping* groups, or could they overlap?  Is the "sample" a part of the dataset (which is what "sample" means) or the whole thing?  Why use groups as an explanatory variable rather than the binary values themselves?

Comment: Thank you @whuber
Yes I used cluster and group as synonyms (sorry for that)

I used the following command the split the data into groups
`
egen group = group(var1 var2 var3 var4)
tab groups
tabstat var1 var2 var3 var4 , by(group)
`
So I guess the groups are non-overlapping

I want to see which composition of explanatory variables has the biggest impact on profit (that's why I used the group variable)

Comment: Does anyone have an idea? 

So my main questions are if the command in my question is appropriate (so using the group variable and not the binary values)? and if there are any examples in management/economics/psychology research that are using this approach?